# How can I use brew and install precommit for Python 3.6.8

Tags: python, git, homebrew, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I want to use **brew to install pre-commit for python 3.6.8**.  I am using macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.7)

I am using `brew install pre-commit` to do the installation.

I am having issues because my pre-commit uses Python 3.9 and I want to avoid this (i.e. make brew pre-commit use python 3.6).

When I try `brew install pre-commit`, I find that automatically one sees the message `Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/python%403.9-3.9.0_2.catalina.bottle.tar.gz`.

The environment that I am on is python 3.6.8. ( `python -V` returns `python 3.6.8`).

Also,

```
username@USERNAME-M-F1AU % echo "$PATH" 
/Users/username/.pyenv/shims:/Users/username/.pyenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I also have, python 3.9 (`python@3.9`), (although it is not the active environment) in `/usr/local/Cellar`. I also have a folder for `pre-commit` inside `/usr/local/Cellar`. Some paths inside subfolders which are inside `/usr/local/Cellar/pre-commit` are linked to python 3.9. Following are examples of the same.

```
python3 -> ../../../../../opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
python -> ../../../../../opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
```

The first line of `/usr/local/bin/pre-commit` is:

`#!/usr/local/Cellar/pre-commit/2.9.0/libexec/bin/python`

I have tried the following already:

- Change of Python environment to Python 3.6. Issue was not solved here (symlinks of pre-commit with python 3.9)
- Deletion of cache (`rm -r /Users/username/.cache/pre-commit`). Same thing happened here (symlinks of pre-commit with python 3.9 still existed).
- Installing of precommit again (`rm -r /usr/local/Cellar/pre-commit` followed by `brew install pre-commit`). Same thing happened here (symlinks of pre-commit with python 3.9).
- Removing and readjusting symlinks using the method shown below.

```
ln -nfs /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/Cellar/pre-commit/2.9.0/libexec/bin/python
ln -nfs /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/Cellar/pre-commit/2.9.0/libexec/bin/python3
```

Here, I got the following error `/usr/local/Cellar/pre-commit/2.9.0/libexec/bin/python3: No module named pre_commit`

**What is the best way in which I can use brew to install pre-commit such that it uses python 3.6 and not python 3.9?**

I saw [this brew precommit page](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pre-commit). It looks like `brew install pre-commit` automatically always uses python 3.9.0.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

brew only really works with the latest versions of software -- they package bottles against the latest version of python

you *can* pin against older formulas, though at this point the 3.6 packages no longer cleanly build (I tried, as a way to show you how to do this, but they've bitrotted)

since it looks like you're using `pyenv` -- probably your best bet is to install a python3.6 using that and then use `pip` to install `pre-commit` from there

I don't use pyenv myself, but if I recall correctly you'd run:

```
pyenv install 3.6.12
pyenv global 3.6.12
```

and then you would use `python3.6 -m pip install pre-commit --user` (you may need to add the `--user` `bin` directory to your `PATH` using your `.bashrc` / `.zshrc`)

---

disclaimer: I'm the creator of pre-commit and I've contributed a bit to the brew formula for it